# How to write JUnit testcase for a method which has private enum in method arguments

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a Spring Controller class which has method defined which accepts private enum as below. How can we write test case for this using Junit/Mockito?

```
@RequestMapping("/getData")
public String getData(
            @RequestParam(value = "someFilter") SomeFilter someFilter)
             {
                // do something
}
```

In above code, SomeFilter is an enum which is defined as a private inside class.

When writing test case for above method, as enum is not visible I cannot call the method, i tried of using Mockito.any(), still no use.

Do we have any way to test above method?

Comment: How does that class get called normally if the SomeFilter isn't accessible from the outside? If it isn't accesible from the outside, why is the method public? You could of course access the enum via Reflection, but the whole thing smells like bad code that needs to be refactored asap.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz great answer, why not post it as answer?

Comment: Thats a Spring method, so it will be called by Spring when invoking the URL. I am not sure how spring maps it internally.

Comment: Sounds to me like the enum should be public.  That would better reflect how it's actually being used.

Comment: Yeah David. But I cannot change the code now to make it public. Is there a way to write test case if enum is private?

Comment: You could put a breakpoint in the method and inspect to stack to see where/how Spring translates the string value in request parameter to the enum value. I won't be surprised if it uses reflection and bypasses access restriction as well. This would justify your using similar approach in the test, though I am not quite sure how you exactly would use to reflection to create an enum value to pass to the method.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Clearly the enum is accessible to the method, so it's visible *enough*.  It's likely defined in the class.  In that case, you should change its visibility to package-private.  This is the *only* way you should get access to it, since doing anything else in practice with tests is considered a code smell at best and poor design at worst.

Comment: What do you mean, you can't change the code?  Why are you testing code that you can't change; and what will you do if your tests reveal a bug in the code?

Answer (score 1):

So, if the method will be called by spring, then you will have to find out, how and replicate that. But honestly, it still smells like horribly bad code, a public method that isn't actually public...

Anyway, you can of course test it via some reflection magic... Let's assume this simple class...

```
public class Testy {

    private enum TestyEnum {
        X,
        y;
    }

    public String someMethod(final TestyEnum testyEnum) {
        return testyEnum.name();
    }

}
```

So, we have a private enum and a public method that accepts it as a paramter. To call it, we have to use reflection...

```
public class TestyTest {

    private final Testy toTest = new Testy();

    @Test
    public void someMethod_should_return_correct_name_of_x() throws Exception {

        // Get the class object for our private enum
        final Class<?> testyEnumClass = Class.forName( "de.assona.iframe.view.Testy$TestyEnum" );

        // List the enum constants
        final Object[] consts = testyEnumClass.getEnumConstants();

        // Get the method via reflection per name and argument type
        final Method method = Testy.class.getMethod( "someMethod", testyEnumClass );

        // call (invoke) it...
        final Object o = method.invoke( this.toTest, consts[0] );

        // And check that the object returned is actually the correct String we expect the name of the private enum constant)
        Assert.assertEquals( "X", o );

    }
}
```

But of course, this is a horrible workaround, bad to read, bad to maintain and the solution for a problem you should not have. Spring does not require you to produce bad code, on the contrary, it solves many problems that lead to bad code. So I would **really** suggest you try to refactor that code to make it testable in a clear, easily maintainable way. Trust me, you (and your fellow codes) will not be happy that you found a way to test bad code, since that makes you keep that bad code. Tested bad code is better than untested bad code, but still bad. You (and your fellow codes) will be much happier in the long run with good code, because it makes everything so much easier...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the method of the controller object, you could test your code with [Spring MockMvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html).

```
public class ControllerTest {
  private final YourController controller = ...
  private final MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
      .build();

  @Test
  public void someTest() throws Exception {
     mockMvc.perform(get("/getData").param("someFilter", "THE_NAME_OF_THE_FILTER"))
       .andExpect(status().isOk())
       .andExpect(content().mimeType("text/html"))
       .andExpect(...);
  }
}
```